# Adding new line to string

Tags: find-and-replace

I have a line that looks something like:

```
186 then some text 185 more text 184 blanks
```

I would like it to be reformatted to look like

```
186 then some text 
185 more text 
184 blanks
```

How can I do this using replace all?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This will work with for lot of languages and tools:

- Find: `(\d+)`
- Replace: `\n$1` or `\n\1` depending on tool, you may use `\r\n` for Windows EOL.

Where:

- `(\d+)` is a capture group that matches 1 or more digits
- `\n` stands for a linefeed, you may use `\r\n` for Windows EOL.
- `$1` or `\1` contains what is matched by group 1 (i.e. 1 or more digits)